# Jolt Transform to add unique identifier in nested array

Tags: json, jolt

I need help in adding a unique identifier to my json packet nested arrays using jolt transform.

I need unique identifier so that if this json packet arrays are exploded i can recreate the same arrays back in same order.

**Input** :

```json
{
  "column1": "value1",
  "column2": {
    "item": [
      {
        "itemname": "x"
      },
      {
        "itemname": "y"
      },
      {
        "itemname": "z"
      }
    ]
  },
  "column3": [
    {
      "itemcat": "a"
    },
    {
      "itemcat": "b"
    },
    {
      "itemcat": "c"
    }
  ]
}
```

**Output** :

```json
{
  "column1": "value1",
  "column2": {
    "item": [
      {
        "itemname": "x",
        "identifier": "item_0"
      },
      {
        "itemname": "y",
        "identifier": "item_1"
      },
      {
        "itemname": "z",
        "identifier": "item_2"
      }
    ]
  },
  "column3": [
    {
      "itemcat": "a",
      "identifier": "column3_0"
    },
    {
      "itemcat": "b",
      "identifier": "column3_1"
    },
    {
      "itemcat": "c",
      "identifier": "column3_2"
    }
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the following transformation

```json
[
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "*": "&", // column1
      "c*2|c*3": { // column2 / 3
        "item": {
          "*": {
            "@": "&3.&2[&1]", // return current key-value pairs
            "$1|$": "&3.&2[&1].identifier" // return the literal "item" along with indexes(0,1,2)
                                           // they constructs array values
          }
        },
        "*": {
          "@": "&2[&1]",
          "$1|$": "&2[&1].identifier"
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "operation": "modify-overwrite-beta",
    "spec": {
      "c*2": {
        "*": {
          "*": {
            "*": "=join('_',@(1,&))" // concatenate the components of the generated arrays
          }
        }
      },
      "c*3": {
        "*": {
          "*": "=join('_',@(1,&))"
        }
      }
    }
  }
]
```

the ***demo*** on the site http://jolt-demo.appspot.com/ is :

[image]

Comment: What if my input contains {
  "column1": "value1",
  "attribute": {
    "col1": "val1",
    "items": [
      {
        "itemname": "x"
      },
      {
        "itemname": "y"
      },
      {
        "itemname": "z"
      }
    ]
  },
  "attributeList": [
    {
      "itemcat": "a"
    },
    {
      "itemcat": "b"
    },
    {
      "itemcat": "c"
    }
  ]
}. It will not return col1 in that case. I just want to execute this on arrays and rest of the json packet should remain same.

Comment: @Datadev You can use `[{ "operation": "shift", "spec": { "column1": "&", "attribute": {
        "*": "&1.&", "items": { "*": { "@": "&3.&2[&1]", "$1|$": "&3.&2[&1].identifier"
          } } }, "*": {    "*": {    "@": "&2[&1]",
          "$1|$": "&2[&1].identifier"
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "operation": "modify-overwrite-beta",
    "spec": {
      "attribute": {
        "*": {
          "*": {
            "*": "=join('_',@(1,&))"
          }
        }
      },
      "*": {
        "*": {
          "*": "=join('_',@(1,&))"
        }
      }
    }
  }
]` then

Comment: This jolt expression is changing the overall structure of the json packet. I just want to edit column2.item and column3 if it is present. Rest of the columns should be there as it is in the output. I have many more columns which are there in the input. Complete packet i can not share in the question.

Comment: @Datadev Unfortunately, there's no swiss army knife solution for Jolt as the case getting more complex. it's nicer to share the minimal one like you did in this case. The rest is upto you. You can try to resemble yours to this one by using similar logic.